# Run a forked JVM with a security manager in sbt

Tags: java, scala, security, sbt

I'm trying to setup a security manager on a JVM forked within sbt. I need to grant permissions to specific libraries. The problem is that sbt copies jar files in temp directories, and loads them from there. Because of this, I cannot specify a proper codebase in my policy file (since I don't know here the jars will be). Is there a solution? Maybe a way to turn off this copying/caching from sbt?